# HtmlUnit: how to select option after other one

Tags: htmlunit

I try to select element of one of dropdown menu after other selection of option on dropdown menu done correctly before.

List of option: optionstemplate, this list was create after one selection of optionsProtocole .

> error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 was returned.

```
/// Select protocole

HtmlSelect selectFieldProtocole = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementByName("protocolNameID");
List<HtmlOption> optionsProtocole = selectFieldProtocole.getOptions();
HtmlOption theOptionProtocole = null;

for (HtmlOption option : optionsProtocole) {
    if (option.getText().equals("dd")) {
        theOptionProtocole = option;
    }
}

selectFieldProtocole.setSelectedAttribute(theOptionProtocole, true);

//// select version

HtmlSelect selectFieldtemplate = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementByName("protocolVersion");

List<HtmlOption> optionstemplate = selectFieldtemplate.getOptions(); 
HtmlOption theOptiontemplate = null;            

for (HtmlOption option : optionstemplate) {
    System.out.println("ma version " + option.getText());

    if (option.getText().equals("dd-V2.1.3")) {
        theOptiontemplate = option;
    }
}

System.out.println("ma version " + optionstemplate.get(0).getText());
// line before return error size zero so,line following don't work 
selectFieldtemplate.setSelectedAttribute(theOptiontemplate, true);
```

HTML :

```
<div id="Upload file">
    <form action="http://qa2tsqat23101v-int.devqa.exch.int/minos/index.php/injector/MateloUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="protocolNameID">
            <label for="protocolNameID"> Protocol Name </label>
            <select name= "protocolNameID" class="protocol_choice" url="http://qa2tsqat23101v-int.devqa.exch.int/minos/index.php/injector/project/choose_protocolNameID/118">
                <option selected="selected" value= 'NULL'>  </option>
                <option value= "127"></option>
                <option value= "19">ARCADIRECT</option>
                <option value= "134">BIN 2</option>
                <option value= "112">BIN MTF</option>
                <option value= "131">Copy ARCADIRECT 2.6W</option>
                <option value= "130">copy Fix4.2</option>
                <option value= "125">copy_test</option>
                <option value= "126">copy_test</option>
                <option value= "116">dd</option>
                <option value= "119">dd - v1.13.0</option>
                <option value= "120">dd 1.13.0-6</option>
                <option value= "117">dd-v1.8.21</option>
                <option value= "8">FIX</option>
                <option value= "114">FOUNDATION</option>
                <option value= "115">Foundation</option>
                <option value= "110">FULL BINARY</option>
                <option value= "118">FullTestCases_5.4.1.s19_ME_CANO1_Limit8_full</option>
                <option value= "999">INTERNAL</option>
                <option value= "122">MIFID2 BIN</option>
                <option value= "123">MIFID2 FIX</option>
                <option value= "999">TBD</option>
                <option value= "121">tccmi</option>
                <option value= "109">TCS BIN</option>
                <option value= "108">TCS FIX</option>
                <option value= "128">TESTTT</option>
                <option value= "129">TESTTTTT</option>
                <option value= "111">UTP DIRECT</option>
                <option value= "132">WSE BIN</option>
                <option value= "133">WSE BIN 2</option>
                <option value= "135">WSE FIX Test</option>
                <option value= "113">XDP D</option>      
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="currentNameID" name="currentNameID" value= "" >
        </div>
        <div id="protocolVersion">
            <label for="protocolVersion"> Version </label>
            <select name= "protocolVersion" class="protocol_choice2"></select>
            <input type="hidden" id="currentVersion" name="currentVersion" value="">
        </div>
```

Comment: after select protocoleID: <select name="protocolVersion" class="protocol_choice" url="http://qa2tsqat23101v-int.devqa.exch.int/minos/index.php/injector/project/choose_protocolVersion/118/116">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="352">dd-V3</option>
<option value="446">V1.15.4-SBE</option>
<option value="526">dd-V2.1.3</option>
<option value="527">V2.0.0-SBE</option>
</select>

Answer (score 2):

If you like to simulate a user selecting something from a list you have to use use the HtmlOption you like to select as starting point.
In general:

1. find the HtmlOption you like to select
2. select this option using myOption.setSelected(true)

This will do all the required background work for you (including deselection or other options if required and event triggering).
And keep in mind, changing the selection will not be reflected by the dom attributes. As a result when using e.g. page.asXML you will still see the same code as before (the selected attribute is still at the original place). If you like to check the the selection you have to use javascript or the isSelected method for the option. Or you can enable HttpClient wire logging and check the submited values on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You may also search and select by index

```
HtmlSelect selectFieldtemplate ...

int selIndex = -1;
for (int i=0; i<selectFieldtemplate.getOptionSize(); i++)
{
    HtmlOption opt = selectFieldtemplate.getOption(i);
    if ( <opt fits criterion> )
    {
        selIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
...
selectFieldtemplate.setSelectedIndex(selIndex);
```